# In Swift, how to "print()" like "p" command in lldb

Tags: swift, debugging, lldb, println

"p *variable*" command prints all the elements within the *variable* in lldb. In Swift, just regular print() statement does not do this. A hack would be to  loop through the backtrace of the variable and print the elements. I'm curious if there is an easier way to simulate the in-depth printing mechanism like the "p" command I'm not aware of.

Comment: You mean like `dump`?

Comment: @Hamish, thanks. (sorta embarrassed)